# How to verify user intent on closing a view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-rcp

If a user clicks on (X) to close a view. Is there a way to pop up a dialog to check if user wants to proceed with the closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that.

1. Simply overwrite `#dispose` of your `ViewPart` and open a Dialog
2. Introduce a dirty state and use the same logic like in editors. Therefore you have to implement `org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablePart` or `org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablePart2` in your `ViewPart`

Comment: Used the ISavablePart in the viewpart and overloaded the methods. It worked! Thanks!